# Where does a Table cell get styled when using focusCellOnPointerMove?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a qx.ui.table.Table that becomes hard to read when a row takes focus.  I'm using qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Date as a base class to override a cell's background color though it doesn't appear this method gets called when
`focusCellOnPointerMove : true` fires events.

So, where is the table getting styled at when a row takes focus?

[image: Example]

Here is my override:

```
// Overridden
_getCellStyle : function(cellInfo)
{
  var diff = 5; // Example
  if (diff < 60)
  {
    var color = '#8cff5e';
    return this.base(arguments, cellInfo) + "background-color:" + color + ";";
  } else if (diff < 60 * 5)
  {
    var color = '#ffff00';
    return this.base(arguments, cellInfo) + "background-color:" + color + ";";
  } else
  {
    return cellInfo.style || "";
  }

},
```

Using suggestion by scro34:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change a table row's background color when it's pointed at you can use qooxdoo's theming capabilities and override the color declaration which comes with the theme you've applied to your application.

The table widget uses two color keys to control the background color when the pointer is hovering over a row: *table-row-background-focused* (unselected row) and *table-row-background-focused-selected* (selected row).

To override the predefined values, open Color.js which is located in the "theme" folder of your application and add two entries to the "colors" section of the file, e.g.:

```
qx.Theme.define("myApp.theme.Color",
{
  extend : qx.theme.indigo.Color,

  colors :
  {
     "table-row-background-focused" : "#8cff5e",
     "table-row-background-focused-selected" : "#ffff00"
  }
});
```

More information about theming in qooxdoo: http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/desktop/ui_theming.html

Tutorial on table styling: http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/desktop/ui_table_styling.html

Comment: While this is helpful, it doesn't quite answer my question about the ultimate location of where an individual cell is being styled. Using this method, gives the same result just a different color. See my update.